# Getting openai.RateLimitError: Error code: 429 (insufficient quota) error, even though never used it

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api

[image]

This is how my "usage" page looks on the platform.openai.com, yet I get this error:

```
openai.RateLimitError: Error code: 429 - {'error': {'message': 'You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details. For more information on this error, read the docs: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/api-errors.', 'type': 'insufficient_quota', 'param': None, 'code': 'insufficient_quota'}}
```

Should I upgrade to a paid plan right away or is there another reason for the error to occur?

Tried using different models, get either `does not exist or you do not have access to it` or the same insufficient quota error.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [docs](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/api-errors), you have a `RateLimitError` and the Cause is **You have hit your assigned rate limit.**

Please note that *Rate limits are restrictions that the API imposes on the number of times a user or client can access their services within a specified period of time.*

To resolve this issue, you should *Pace your requests*. Visit [Rate limits](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/rate-limits?context=tier-free) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Tl;dr: Your free tokens are Expired. You can see that most of your usage bar is Pink = Expired. Go buy tokens.

Alright, I understand your issue because I had the same problem.

I agree you never used the api before this, however, you have *signed up* for an OpenAI account more than 3 months ago.

As stated in the official OpenAI article:

> To explore and experiment with the API, all new users get $5 worth of
> free tokens. **These tokens expire after 3 months.**
>
> After the quota has passed you can choose to enter billing information
> to upgrade to a paid plan and continue your use of the API on
> pay-as-you-go basis. If no billing information is entered you will
> still have login access, but will be unable to make any further API
> requests.
>
> Please see the pricing page for the latest information on
> pay-as-you-go pricing.

So, basically, as you can see, **your free tokens are Expired** because **they weren't used within 3 months of you creating an OpenAI account (you must have created an account more than 3 months ago)**.

You can see in the image below that **most of the bar is Pink in colour**. That means your free tokens expired.

[image: The expired part]

So, how do you solve this?

Well, you pay. Go buy a paid plan, fill it up with like, 5 dollars, the payment process is relatively simple. After that, lo and behold, the error goes away.

Well, that's what worked for me anyways. Hope it helps.